# Problem with React Class Component Not Behaving Same as React Hook with onScroll Init

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a React Class Component that behaves the same (and correctly) as a React Hook I've developed.  The example I have in stackblitz and shown here does not show the correct images when the page first loads. Once a scroll event happens it becomes correct.

I've got the following example that shows the incorrect behavior.  You can see the correct behavior by changing the import statement to the one that is currently commented out. The hook breaks the same way when I remove the isLoading from the dependency array of useEffect.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scroll-problem

NOTE: Changing isLoading to false in constructor solves problem, but adds a double display of the image (first b&w, then color) which hooks does not have.

```
import * as React from "react";

class ImageToggleOnScrollCC extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.imgRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      inView: false,
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  isInView = imageRefx => {
    if (this.imgRef.current) {
      const rect = this.imgRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      return rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight;
    }
    return false;
  };

  scrollHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      inView: this.isInView()
    });
  };

  // componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  //   console.log("componentDidUpdate")
  //   if (this.props.isLoading !== prevProps.isLoading) {
  //     console.log("componentDidUpdate isLoading changed")
  //   }
  // }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler);
    this.setState({
      inView: this.isInView(),
      isLoading: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <i>ImageToggleOnScrollCC - Class Component</i>
          <br />
          <img
            src={
              this.state.inView
                ? 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png/0000FF/808080?text=ON-SCREEN'
                : 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png?text=off-screen'
            }
            alt=""
            ref={this.imgRef}
            width="200"
            height="200"
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default ImageToggleOnScrollCC;
```

Below is the working React Hook Component that I want the Class component above to work just like.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ImageTogglerOnScroll = ({ primaryImg, secondaryImg }) => {
  const imageRef = useRef(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    setInView(isInView());
    setIsLoading(false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    };
  }, [isLoading]);

  const [inView, setInView] = useState(false);

  const isInView = () => {
    if (imageRef.current) {
      const rect = imageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      return rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const scrollHandler = () => {
    setInView(() => {
      return isInView();
    });
  };

  return isLoading ? null : (
    <div>
      <i>ImageToggleOnScroll - Functional Component React Hooks</i>
      <br />
      <img
        src={inView ? secondaryImg : primaryImg}
        alt=""
        ref={imageRef}
        width="200"
        height="200"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageTogglerOnScroll;
```

Comment: Please include all the code necessary for a [mcve] in this post. Linking to the "working version" somewhere else is fine, but the question really does need to contain all the code relevant to the question so people can comment on the code you're showing, not "some code that might change from one minute to the next on another site". On a small JS note: why `import * as React from "react";`? All you tap into is the Component class, so `import { Component } from "react";` should work just fine?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've updated the post to include the working hook. I put a lot of time into making this question and am surprised at the criticism and the downvote. The code I posted is not working correctly.  It is minimal, it is verifiable and it is complete.  I thought I would have been slammed for posting working code as violating some SO "Excess information not necessary" rule. I see you have a lot of reputation and am frankly a little surprised. I've spent a lot of time on forums in my life and I did put good effort into being clear.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans regard the import, it was not necessary as you point out but does not have any impact on the question. It was put in by a code template and I did not remove it.

Comment: Of course not, it was just a small JS note. Also on a point of policy: I didn't downvote, I just asked for the code because SO posts should have all the details in them, even if they link out to external sites, which was not the case yet. Without the hook's code, people who really know their React can't see what you did different in your class. In effect, they can't see the proof that your two pieces of code behave differently without _leaving_ SO, and so have no reason to not just move on to a question that doesn't require them to go on a fact finding mission.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for letting me know you didn't down vote, it just happened at the same time as your comment so I assumed.I understand why you asked, though try to stick to "less is more" and only posted problem code. I have taken your suggestion and posted the working code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that both components need to be rendered at least three times to show not only the image, but also the correct image loaded when `inView`.

1. The initial render, which will set `isLoading` to true.
2. Only after `isLoading` has been set to true it is, when the image is being rendered and the ref to the element will be assigned.
3. After that, your component can trace back to the `img` element, determine it's position and mark it as `inView` or not.

In the hook component you have `useEffect((), obj)` which checks for any change of `obj` (this case `[isLoading]`) and then triggers a rerender on the component in the hook version. This leads to a rerender once `isLoading` changed and runs step 2 and 3.

Meanwhile, in the class component, the 3rd step never actually runs (without the user manually triggering a scroll event): It renders the first time, then in `componentDidMount()` sets `isLoading` to `false` and that's it. Because at that point in time the image ref has not been set yet, `isInView()` returns `false` and no more code is being run. This class component is missing the check for subsequent `isLoading` changes.

Here is a way to implement that check in the class component:

```
class ImageToggleOnScrollCC extends React.Component {
  // ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.isLoading !== prevState.isLoading) {
      console.log("componentDidUpdate isLoading changed")
      console.log("this.imgRef.current is also assigned at this time", this.imgRef.current)

      this.setState({
        inView: this.isInView(), // will return true and rerender
      });
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```